# trigger function in postgresql not working some help needed simple code

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers

I need to make a trigger function that copies the data inserted in a table to another table that has other column names.

here is the insert statement that shows the content of my new table :

```
INSERT INTO public.mvt(
    idtraitements, 
    mode, 
    direction,
    date_, 
    heure, 
    rfid_qr_rtag, 
    matricule, 
    idpersonnel)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

here is the select statement of the source table :

```
SELECT "IDTraitements", mode, "Direction", date, heure, "RFID_QR_RTAG", 
    "Matricule", "IDPersonnel"
    FROM public."MVT_PNT";
```

here is the trigger function but it doesn't run :

```
create or replace function emp_log_copy() returns trigger language 'plpgsql'
as $$
begin
insert into mvt(idtraitements, mode, direction, date_, heure, 
    rfid_qr_rtag, matricule, idpersonnel) 
    values (
        new."IDTraitements" ,
        new."mode" ,
        new."Direction"  ,
        new.date ,
        new.heure,
        new."RFID_QR_RTAG" ,
        new."Matricule" ,
        new."IDPersonnel");
end;
$$
```

trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER emp_log_copynewt
  AFTER INSERT
  ON "MVT_PNT"
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE emp_loging();
```

some help would be appreciated!
it is not me who created the table "MVT_PNT" but i need to work with it as it is.

Comment: you must add the `RETURN` Clause to the END of trigger function: `RETURN NEW;`

Comment: can u please explain why and what would return null would mean ? @AnthonySotolongo

Comment: just tried it with return new it still doesn't work i inserted in "MVT-PNT"  nothing showed up in mvt

Comment: return some error? can you put a `raise notice 'here';` after the `INSERT` clause inside the trigger function?

Comment: i did but still nothing it successfully inserts in the fiirst table a no copy in the second one

Comment: please double-check your code in the trigger definition you call `emp_loging()` function and your trigger function is named `emp_log_copy()`

Answer (score 0):

@regragui-karim, please check the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)

> A trigger function must return either NULL or a record/row value having exactly the structure of the table the trigger was fired for.